# Trying to use two IFrames on a page each pointing to an aspx page. How to trigger a refresh from the Code behind of one to the other

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I want to display two windows on a page.  Currently I'm trying it with 2 Iframes.  The left window will primarily be images.  The right will be primarily controls.   On the controls window if I hit a button I need to cause a refresh to the images window.  I planned to use query strings or session variables to pass info.

I've been trying to find a way to call up into the parent window possibly calling a jQuery function to call the page.  Not sure how to get to the controls in parent.

The IFrames on my page are

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <table border="0" class="Worldmap">
        <tr id="hidethis" style="display: ;">
            <td>
                <iframe src="WorldMapView2.aspx" id="Iframe1" name=" page1" align="center"
                    marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="No" noresize scrolling="auto" height="1000"
                    width="1000" runat="server" target="_top"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <table border="0">
        <tr id="hidethis2" style="display: ;">
            <td>
                <iframe src="Controls.aspx" id="Iframe2" name=" page2" align="center"
                    marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="No" noresize scrolling="auto" height="700"
                    width="250" runat="server" target="_top"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

From within Content.aspx code behind how can I call a function on the parent that will refresh WorldMapView2...thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a javascript function on the page containing both the Iframes.

```
<script>
    function refreshIframe() {
        var $iframe = $('#<%= Iframe1.ClientID %>');
        $iframe.attr('src', $iframe.attr('src'));
    }
</script>
```

And then call if from `Controls.aspx`

```
<button onclick="parent.refreshIframe()" type="button">Refresh Iframe1</button>
```

This only work if all the pages are on the same domain.